# Coverage support for tornado test runner

Tags: python, unit-testing, tornado, coverage.py

I need to get coverage reports for a project I've based in tornado.

But I can't get the configuration for coverage to use the tornado runner instead of the one in the standard library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it's just

```
coverage run /the/test/runner options to test runner
```

sometimes with a `--source=thepackage` to remove cruft.

What happens when you run that?

Comment: Yeah, din't think of that.. Thanks.